# I am trying to determine is C is OK with '!' in its precompiler

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The line in question is:

```
#if ! defined(_VALUE)
    foo = 23;
#endif
```

It seems to build, but I am not sure its behavior is as expected.

Comment: It's fine, it's logical negation in the preprocessor. In this case, it's true if `_VALUE` is *not* defined as a macro.

Comment: On another note, names beginning with a single underscore followed by an upper-case letter are [*reserved*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers). You should not define such symbol-names yourself, neither as preprocessor macros nor as function or variable names.

Comment: On anothe note: you also have `#ifdef FOO` which is the same as `#if defined(FOO)` and `#ifndef FOO` which is the same as `#if !defined(FOO)`

Comment: You can also use other arithmetic and logical operators which can be useful for reducing the number of nested `#if` directives. E.g. by replacing `#ifdef FOO` `#ifdef BAR` ... `#endif` `#endif` with `#if defined(FOO) && defined(BAR)` ... `#endif`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example tells the preprocessor to exclude the text if "_VALUE" is defined; else to include it.

Most compilers give you an option to "display preprocessor output", e.g. "-E" for gcc:

**x.c**

```
#if ! defined(MY_DEFINITION)
    foo = 23;
#endif
```

**Sample output:**

```
$ gcc -E x.c
# 1 "x.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x.c"

    foo = 23;

$ gcc -E -DMY_DEFINITION x.c
# 1 "x.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x.c"
```

Here is a good overview: [C - Preprocessors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm)

Comment: I thought my example includes the text if _VALUE is NOT defined.  Am I confused?

Comment: @Jiminion you are correct. In this case, it looks like `_VALUE` is not defined. This may be different from on your computer

Comment: @Jiminion: You're correct; my bad.  I edited my reply.  Hopefully it's helpful for you.